# Why do I get error Expected end of input but got keyword SELECT?

Tags: sql, subquery

What I do to get this query right?

[Query with error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfC4U.png)

I tried to create a subquery using the SELECT clause and I get an error:

> Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword SELECT at [5:3]

Comment: In the future, please don't link to images. First, it forces people to click an unknown link. Second, if people want to copy/paste to try your code locally that doesn't work with an image. Plain text in the question body is good. Your query looks to have a few syntax issues.

Comment: The future is now. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: A [mre] includes: cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. PS Clearly your goal & error(s) will be old asked & answered Q&A. But one must pin down via a [mre] & write many clear, concise & precise phrasings of one's question/problem/goal to search reasonably.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your query you are missing the group by clause before the FROM.

```
select ...,
  COUNT(Orders.order_id) as number_of_orders,
  (select ... group by orders.order_id)
FROM `..`
```